# Import Excel file into ngx-datatable - Angular 8

Tags: excel, angular8, ngx-datatable

I have seen multiple posts on exporting ngx-datatable to csv/xlsx. However, I did not come across any post which says Import Excel file into ngx-datatable which is basically what I need. I need to read an excel file that user uploads and display into ngx-datatable (so basically excel file acting as source for ngx-datatable)

Any guidelines / help links to proceed will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can transform into an csv file, there is this lib called ngx-csv-parser (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-csv-parser) that helps to format data in object array, the way you need to send to a ngx-datatable. It says it is designed for Angular 13 but has compability with previous versions. I've tested it in Angular 10 and it does work.

It has a setting to use header or no. If you do, you can shape your columns prop from ngx-datatable with the same name of the header.

Example:
Lets say you have a csv file like this:

```
ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC
a,b,c
```

The output of using this lib (the way it is said in its readme) with header= true will be:

```
csvRecords = [{ColumnA: a, ColumnB: b, ColumnC: c}]
```

Lets say you also have an array of columns:

```
columns = [
{name="A", prop: ColumnA},
{name="B", prop: ColumnB},
{name="C", prop: ColumnC}
]
```

Then use columns and csvRecords in your html.

```
<ngx-datatable
        class="material"
        [rows]="csvRecords"
        [columns]="columns"
      >
</ngx-datatable>
```

Your table will be filled with data from your csv.